# Client-Server socket communication between Android and Python?

Tags: python, android, sockets, server, client

I would like to use sockets for a client-server communication between Python and Android. Currently I established a connection from Android to the Python server. This works well. I can also send messages to the server. Now I tried to send a response to Android.

The python code:

```
 clientsocket.send(bytes("Testmessage","UTF-8"))
```

There is no error.
In the Android app, I tried to get the result via BufferedReader:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
Log.e("Test",""+in.read()); // returns 84
Log.e("Test2",""+in.readLine()); // no console output
```

Any idea how I could fix it?

Comment: `"Testmessage"` replace by `"Testmessage\n"`.

Comment: `Log.e("Test",""+in.read()); ` Remove that statement.

Comment: Thanks. I simply had to finish the Line with \r\n.

Comment: The point is that your Android code tries to read a line. So your Python code should send a line too. A line is a string ending on \n.